# is it possible to change default md_document output for lists from `## [1]` to `1.` for enumerated list?

Tags: r, knitr

When creating markdown documents with knitr, a default format for a list looks like

```
##  [1] item 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
##  [2] item 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
##  [3] thing 3
```

This is fine for some situations, but in other cases, it would be nice for the output to take the form of an enumerated list like show, which will text warp and indent for easy viewing on GitHub.

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. thing 3

Is there an easy opts_chunk setting to change to modify the output?

Comment: you can set chunk option `comment` to `FALSE` and create your own printing function to display it as a result, or you can integrate it in your text with ```r paste0(seq_along(vec),". ",vec,collapse="\n")```  (add simple quotes around this, i don't know how to escape them here).